Unable to install python dependencies for Firebase CLI
Helllo, I have been able to access Firestore as well as deploy code for firestore and hosting, but I am unable to do firebase init functions nor firebase deploy --only functions.
Currently these are the lines i am receiving in Firebase CLI
? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? Python
? File functions/requirements.txt already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/requirements.txt
? File functions/.gitignore already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/.gitignore
? File functions/main.py already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/main.py
? Do you want to install dependencies now? Yes
The system cannot find the path specified.

and this is what i see in the debug log
[debug] [2024-05-22T09:43:08.808Z] Running command with virtualenv: command="C:\firebase_cli\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat", args=["","&&","pip3","install","--upgrade","pip"]
[debug] [2024-05-22T09:43:08.850Z] Error: spawn "C:\firebase_cli\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat" ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\<user>\.cache\firebase\tools\lib\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\<user>\.cache\firebase\tools\lib\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\<user>\.cache\firebase\tools\lib\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

I am relatively new to deploying code in general, so help would be much appreciated
have tried pip install the virtualenv by itself, but main issue seems to be about system not being able to locate right path? to be honest im not sure what is happening
